# React doesn't respect package.json version

Tags: reactjs, npm

In my `package.json` file I have specified the react version as `"react": "^16.13.1"`

I then run `npm install` to install the dependencies, however when I run `npm run start` the project is built with the react version of my terminal, instead of the version specified in the package.json file.

Running `npm view react version` returns `17.0.2` which is what npm uses to build the project, even though package.json specifies 16.13.1.

How can I force the terminal to use the specified version of react, or how do I downgrade to v16 in the terminal?

I am using Git Bash in Windows 10.

Comment: Make sure React is listed under "dependencies" and not "devDependencies" in your `package.json`

Comment: Yep, react is under "dependencies" and not "devDependencies"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was react was installed globally, so there were conflicting versions. Uninstalled with `npm uninstall -g react` and the problem went away.

Also, thanks everyone for pointing out that `npm view react version` returns the latest *available* version instead of the currently installed one.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong command.

`npm view react version` shows you the latest version of React that is *available to install*. If you want to see what version you have currently installed, use `npm ls react`.

Comment: Thanks! `npm ls react` made me realize the problem was because react was also globally installed